# why there is huge different running time cost in each task?

Tags: apache-spark

[image]

Why slave4 cost too much time but slave5 and slave8 cost so little?Even though the hardware of slave4 is older than other two nodes,but the difference in cost time is so huge,why?

Comment: Can you provide us some more details? Code sample which you are using. From the screenshot it seems there are different task running on it.

Answer (score 0):

Without code of your job I cannot be 100% sure, but I would assume that you've done some grouping instead of doing reduction first.

It seems like every node except for slave4 send all the data to slave4, and he did all the computations.

It's very common error at the beggining.